# Rails app works locally but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

my app was working locally.  I deployed to heroku and am getting an application error.  I cant seem to figure out what is wrong.  Posting logs below, does anything stick out?

error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

logs

heroku logs

```
2014-07-04T04:40:15.871014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-04T04:40:16.982435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"     method=GET path="/" host=kitchen-ninja.herokuapp.com request_id=aa152804-e6f0-4a2f-9c27-   c9fb580272f3 fwd="100.1.249.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-04T04:40:17.620440+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kitchen-ninja.herokuapp.com request_id=a3c43716-35b3-43b5-9426-fb2f3f400c1b fwd="100.1.249.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-04T04:40:17.783162+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kitchen-ninja.herokuapp.com request_id=2a8c63d7-3906-48c7-85de-abe64c2fd247 fwd="100.1.249.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-04T04:40:15.860319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'


gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'mail_form', '~> 1.5.0.rc'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.1'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'pony'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'paperclip', '4.1'
gem 'devise'

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
    gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
end 

group :test do

end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: 503 is Service unavailable...  Have you made sure your DB instance is up on heroku?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you have to deployed to heroku, you need to run rake db:migrate before it starts work. Go to the folder you pushed the app from and do a

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This should fix the 503 errors you are having.

Answer (score 6):

There are two types of error of Rails apps on Heroku:

**Heroku**

[image]

This means *Heroku* has a problem at platform-level (I.E Rails cannot be loaded). This is typically a `database` issue, which can be resolved by either ensuring your `db` is created, or running the `heroku run rake db:migrate` command from your CMD

--

**Rails**

[image]

This is a *Rails* specific error, caused when you hit a Rails app which has problems *internally*. This will only show if the entire Heroku platform is running well, meaning if you have a `db` set up etc - meaning something inside your code is broken

---

The difference here is that one error is `platform` specific, whilst the other is `application` specific. If you have the above (`Heroku`) error, you need to make sure you can fix any of the issues you have on the `Heroku` platform itself -- which can be done by using:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This is, of course, considering you have a database set up for your Rails application. If this is the case, you need to make sure you have a database set up in production, and then you've set the correct authentication details in `config/database.yml`

Answer (score 1):

I ran
    heroku run rails console

that gave me a much better understanding of what was wrong.  Turns out I had an unexpected end in my users controller...

```
heroku run rails console
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.6073
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-  
4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require':     
/app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:68: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, 
expecting    end-of-input (SyntaxError)
```

Comment: have you found solution ? kindly share with us

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but if you get apps crashing in heroku with no reason/H10 error code on logs, ensure you are using Puma. I faced the same with nothing working but adding Puma to fix it. Basically:

1. Add Puma to your Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'puma'
   ```
2. Set Puma as the server for your web process in the Procfile:

   ```
   web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
   ```
3. Create a configuration file for Puma at `config/puma.rb`.
   Heroku recommends the following, but customize for your needs

   ```
   workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2) 
   threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
   threads threads_count, threads_count<br/>
   preload_app!<br/>
   rackup DefaultRackup<br/>
   port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
   environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'<br/>
   on_worker_boot do
       ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
   end
   ```

More information can be found at heroku.com: [Deploying Rails Applications with the Puma Web Server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server).

Comment: hello Evandro, Please add relevant information from that link to your answer. Link-only answers are often marked for deletion as links can change and hence invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I spend really a lot of time as beginner to Ruby on Rails, to find the solution. Thanks to Shyam Bhimani who gave it to me on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484181/cloud9-github-and-heroku-the-page-you-were-looking-for-doesnt-exist). Anyway, the solution is like the following:

NB: you should be inside front your SSH screen, inside your application folder. Now type the following :

```
$ bundle update 

$ heroku run rake db:migrate

$ heroku run rake db:schema:load

$ git init

$ git add .

$ git commit -am "some comment"

$ git push heroku master

$ git push heroku master

$ heroku open
```

I was so happy to get my application works on Heroku, and I'm wrting this answer, to help you as Shayam helped me. Regards