# Cloud9, GitHub and Heroku (The page you were looking for doesn't exist.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, cloud9

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm usin:
 / Cloud9 to make the ROR application
 / GitHub to store the files and update them
 / Hiroku for the production as a free service

When I run the application on Cloud9, it works properly:
https://ruby2016-bbparis.c9users.io/

When I push it to GitHub, it doesn't work on Heroku, and I get :

The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

[capture screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C36Ub.png)

My route file is so simple :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'

  get 'pages/about', to: 'pages#about'

end
```

How can I resolve this issue please ?

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access? Please provide more information

Comment: This one: https://blog2017.herokuapp.com

Comment: Type heroku logs -t  on your development machine and try to access your app, then add the log to your answer

Comment: I got the following in purple color : 2016-05-27T13:42:50.363619+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=blog2017.herokuapp.com request_id=c9254642-e6e9-4fd1-88df-35fc6969b072 fwd="78.192.105.48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=1829

Comment: at=info method=GET path="/" host=blog2017.herokuapp.com request_id=1e365734-db62-40cc-b149-c59a78411867 fwd="2.234.126.195" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1829

Comment: What's in your PostController?

Comment: I don't have any post control, just pages_controller.rb like the following class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def home
    
    end
    
    def about
    
    end

end

Comment: my application is so simple, I didn't make something complicated, just modify the routes.rb / add pages_controller.rb / and 2 simple pages, about and home

Comment: Sorry, I meant PageController. Ok, did you add the views under app/views/pages?

Comment: exactly, about.html.erb and home.html.erb in the foloder pages inside views

Comment: in fact, the application works fine on Cloud9 https://ruby2016-bbparis.c9users.io/

Comment: Please include your controller files in question. include your heroku logs.

Comment: my files are available on the following link : https://github.com/bbparis/ruby2017

Comment: log is here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eMzo00xWEQ1ahVOJO-fW11btaE0nqfneez5TwvtPnvg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already have heroku repository created.
Try following command and it should work as your app works perfectly on c9

```
$ bundle update 

$ heroku run rake db:migrate

$ heroku run rake db:schema:load

$ git init

$ git add .

$ git commit -am "some comment"

$ git push heroku master

$ git push heroku master

$ heroku open
```

I know your page doesn't have even database yet. I had similar problem in past and it helped me to resolve same problem.

run `rake db:schema:load` basically load your schema into current environment's database. `rake db:migrate` does migration for current environment which not run yet for more info on rake db commands follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload)

It is recommended to use `postgres` database in heroku because of tight integration with platform however there are many option for application currently running on `MySQL`. For more information on how you can migrate to `postgres` [click here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql).

Comment: Thank you so much Shyam !!!! it works Youuuuupeeee, I spent on it a lot of time. Could you please tell me what is happen exactly ? and also a question, if I use MySql, I will have a problem ? as if I understand good, Heroku doesn't accept MySQL, no?

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. I have edited my answer to provide more clear idea.  @bbparis